# Javascript not working in php normally its working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fancybox-2

I am creating a pop up.I am using fancybox ,it is working fine when I include it normally in html as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($){
       $.fancybox.open([{
          content: $('<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Gmail</a>')
       }]); 
    });
</script>
```

But when i write the same quote in drupal_add_js its not working:

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       $.fancybox.open([{
          content: $("<a href=\'http://www.google.com\' target=\'_blank\'>Gmail</a>")
       }]); 
    });','inline');
```

I am passing it as inline java script,someone can tell me what is the error due to which its happening.I have included the fancybox js and css.

Comment: check the generated javascript. i would assume `drupal_add_js` takes a path not the actual js

Comment: The codes area not exactly the same.

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7   Please view this it says it takes js directly as well

Comment: @Ibu you can use inline code with it.

Comment: You're using single quotes around the attributes in the 2nd version. Both are valid in JS but html requires double quotes

Comment: @ChristianDechery can you please tell me what the change needs to be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe drupal set noConfilct on jQuery so you'll have to set the parameter of the ready function to `$`

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function($){
       $.fancybox.open([{
          content: $("<a href=\'http://www.google.com\' target=\'_blank\'>Gmail</a>")
       }]); 
});','inline');
```

Comment: make sure fancybox is already included before call this code.

Comment: I have added the fancybox js and css in the folder and given its path in .info file

Comment: When the page loads it automatically loads all js and css

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked for me. I explicity called the js file using drupal_Add_js function and rest all code was same. Its working absolutely fine as required by me. Thanks a lot for help.

```
drupal_add_js('jquery.fancybox.js');
            drupal_add_js('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js');
            drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       $.fancybox.open([{
          content: $("<a href=\'http://www.google.com\' target=\'_blank\'>Gmail</a>")
       }]); 
});', 'inline');
```